# Fragment shader input interfering with texture access

Tags: opengl, glsl, jogl

I am using a vertex, geometry and fragment shader to render a scene with shadows:

**Vertex Shader:**

```
#version 400
layout(location=0) in vec3 position;
out vec4 vShadowCoord;
uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 shadowMatrix;
void main(void)
{
    vShadowCoord = shadowMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

**Geometry Shader:**

```
#version 400
layout(triangles_adjacency) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;
in vec4 vShadowCoord[];
out vec4 gShadowCoord;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

void main()
{
    gShadowCoord = vShadowCoord[0];
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    gShadowCoord = vShadowCoord[2];
    gl_Position = gl_in[2].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    gShadowCoord = vShadowCoord[4];
    gl_Position = gl_in[4].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
#version 400
in vec4 shadowCoord;
out vec4 fColor;
uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap;

void main(void)
{
    float shadow = textureProj(shadowMap, shadowCoord);
    fColor = (shadow > 0.0) ? vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) : vec4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
}
```

This successfully renders my scene with shadows. The cubes in my scene are lit and in shadow where I would expect them to be. The problem occurs when I try to pass one of the two colors in from the geometry shader. When I do this, my conditional statement always evaluates to false.

**Geometry shader:**

```
#version 400
layout(triangles_adjacency) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;
in vec4 vShadowCoord[];
out vec4 gShadowCoord; // Added
out vec4 gColorLit;    // Added
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

void main()
{
    gShadowCoord = vShadowCoord[0];
    gColorLit = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // Added
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    gShadowCoord = vShadowCoord[2];
    gColorLit = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // Added
    gl_Position = gl_in[2].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    gShadowCoord = vShadowCoord[4];
    gColorLit = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // Added
    gl_Position = gl_in[4].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 400
in vec4 shadowCoord;
in vec4 gColorLit; // Added
out vec4 fColor;
uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap;

void main(void)
{
    float shadow = textureProj(shadowMap, shadowCoord);
    // Changed
    fColor = (shadow > 0.0) ? gColorLit : vec4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
}
```

What could be causing this to happen?

This occurs on both Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7

Some of the code in my shaders might seem unnecessary, but that is because I have stripped as much as I could away while troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason for your second shaders to successfully *link*. Your geometry shader states that it's writing:

```
out vec4 gShadowCoord; // Added
```

But your fragment shader is expecting:

```
in vec4 shadowCoord;
```

You should have gotten a linker error.